# In excel, How to compare multiple values in single cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

| 123,123,123 |
| --- |
| 456,789,456,258,652 |

I have 3 values in a single cell and have 5 values in the next cell delimited by a comma.
I want to compare all the values in the A1, if they all are unique the result should be True.
if not unique the result should be false.

Expected Output:

| 123,123,123 | True |
| --- | --- |
| 456,789,456,258,652 | False |

How to do this in excel. Kindly provide me an idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check [Split text into different columns with the Convert Text to Columns Wizard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7) so you can split those numbers into different cells and get advantage of using some common formulas.

Comment: What I see is if the values in a cell are same then it's true othewise it's false. Is that correct?

Comment: You can create a VBA function that does exactly that. Unless there is a limited number of comma delimited numbers, I do not believe you can do that using a formula.

Comment: If A1 is text, you could use a formula `=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1),""),",",""))=0`

Comment: It's fairly simple through formulae if you know how to use `FILTERXML()` to split the string into an array and analyse it through an xpath expression. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194)

Comment: @Bharat ..yes..But how to do that..splitting is not possible as I have a different count of values in each cell

Comment: @ Nathan_Sav it worked.Thank you so much

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, `=SUBSTITUTE(A1&",",LEFT(A1&",",FIND(",",A1)),"")=""` will do too I guess.

Comment: @JvdV will that need a final comma though?

Comment: I'd say so in case it's a numeric value on it's own without a 2nd number which would be comma-seperated @Nathan_Sav

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple implementation with VBA, however with formula also it could be possible

```
Sub CheckIfSame()
    Dim counter As Integer
    'Dim arrSplitStrings1() As Variant
    counter = 2
    Do While True
        If Cells(counter, 1) <> "" Then
            Cells(counter, 2) = ElementsSame(Split(Cells(counter, 1), ","))
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
       counter = counter + 1
    Loop

End Sub

Function ElementsSame(arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim l As Long
    ElementsSame = True
    For l = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(0) <> arr(l) Then
            ElementsSame = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next l
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on [VAR.S() function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/var-s-function-913633de-136b-449d-813e-65a00b2b990b) and `Evaluate()`. If all the numbers are equal then `VAR.S()=0`

```
Function IsEqual(txt As String)
    IsEqual = Evaluate("VAR.S(" & txt & ")") = 0
End Function
```